# Any Islamic evidence to she camel came from the rocks to thamud people?

Tags: history, reference-request

Any Quran or hadith evidence to she camel came from the rocks to thamud people?

Comment: What exactly is the issue the qur'an clearly states that it was a she camel ناقة.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think the question is about the "coming out of a rock" part.

Comment: @TheZ yeah I was just trying to figure out whether this actually is the case, as I don't know of any possible evidence.